# In Outlook Office365 web interface, how to find all calendar events with attachments?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, calendar

I do not have access to the desktop application, only the web interface of Office365.

I commonly receive calendar invites with attachments, but cannot find them in my inbox after accepting the invite. If search in the calendar, there is a filter flag to find attachments, but it requires a search term and leaving it blank or wildcards return nothing.

The only way to consistently find them is to go directly to the event in the calendar.

I understand that this is easily done in the desktop application. Is there any way in the web interface?

My ideal would be a filter group that shows all my calendar events with attachments so that it is always up to date. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, I'm afraid that it is not achieveable. We could only use the filter to search among events with attachments.